# Memory allocation and constructor

Tags: c++, memory-management, allocation

I am sorry if it has been asked before explicitly stated in the standard, but I fail to find whether the memory for objects with automatic storage is allocated in the beginning of enclosing block or immediately before executing the constructor?

I am asking this because https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration says that.

> Storage duration
> All objects in a program have one of the following storage durations:

> automatic storage duration. The storage for the object is allocated at the beginning of the enclosing code block and deallocated at the end. All local objects have this storage duration, except those declared static, extern or thread_local.

Now, does it mean that the storage space is allocated even where constructor is not invoked for some reason?

For example, I have something like that.

```
{
     if(somecondition1) throw something;
     MyHugeObject o{};
     /// do something
}
```

So, there a chance that MyHugeObject does not need to be constructed, yet according to the source I've cited, the memory for it is still allocated, despite the fact that the object might never get constructed. Is it the case or it is something implementation based?

Comment: What if `MyHugeObject`'s constructor can `throw`?  So it would make sense that the compiler would not construct the object until it is actually going to be used.

Comment: Keep in mind that your quoted source is subject to the as-if rule, so the compiler is still allowed to play fast and loose with the storage duration as long as no side-effect occurs from it.

Comment: Too anecdotal to be an answer, but in my experience most compilers just allocate all stack space up front (it's a single instruction anyway) regardless of whether it will be used. See [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/6eM2PR)

Comment: The memory could still be allocated up front if the compiler sees that `somecondition` has no effect on the construction of `MyHugeObject`, even if the constructor can `throw`.  Better to just put the code after the `throw` in its own `{ }` block, just to be sure.

Comment: I believe it's completely implementation-defined. With a typical stack-based implementation, this "allocation" is represented just by some offsets hard-coded in the program assembly.

Comment: Note that in C, the storage duration is indeed linked to the enclosing block (storage duration and lifetime are directly linked in C). But in C++, storage duration is not directly linked to the lifetime - it can be longer. Maybe that's where the confusion stems from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, from a language standard perspective, **you cannot access the object's storage outside of the lifetime of the object**. Before the object is created, you do not know where the object is located, and after it has been destructed, accessing the storage yields undefined behavior. In short: **A conforming C++ program cannot observe the difference of when the storage is allocated**.

Automatic storage typically means "on the call-stack". I.e. allocation happens by decrementing the stack pointer, and deallocation happens be re-incrementing it. A compiler *could* emit code that does the stack pointer adjustments exactly where the lifetime of the object starts/ends, but this is inefficient: It would clutter the generated code with two extra instructions for each object that is used. This is especially a problem with objects that are created in a loop: The stack pointer would jump back and forth between two or more positions constantly.

To improve efficiency, compilers huddle all possible object allocations together into a single **stack frame allocation**: The compiler assigns an offset to each variable within the function, determines the max. size that is required to store all the variables that are present within the function, and allocates all the memory with a single stack pointer decrement instruction at the start of the function execution. Cleanup is then the respective stack pointer increment. This removes any allocation/deallocation overhead from loops as the variables in the next iteration will simply reuse the same spot within the stack frame as the previous iteration used. **This is an important optimization, for many loops declare at least one variable.**

The C++ standard does not care. Since use of the storage outside of an object's lifetime is UB, the compiler is free to do with the storage whatever it pleases to do. Programmers should not care as well, but they do tend to care about their programs execution times. And that's what most compilers optimize for by using stack frame allocation.

Comment: The thing is that there might be a difference.If I understand it right, if else might require less memory than writing same code after return or throw statement.

Comment: @RazielMagius The compiler is free to allocate the variables for the different `if() {int i;} else {int j;}` clauses at the same memory location: Their lifetimes don't overlap, so they cannot interfere with one another. Unless the program has undefined behavior, of course.

Comment: @RazielMagius Btw: Worrying about memory consumption in the `throw` case seems a bit pointless to me: Exceptions, if they are used at all, should be used for exceptional circumstances, only. You should write the function expecting it to reach the object creation virtually in any case. Exceptions are way too expensive to be used in the main code paths. It's like worrying about the costs for a parking space when you fear that your car dealer damages the car on delivery, forcing them to refund you for the car instead of delivering it.

Comment: What I meant, is that given equivalent { if(condition)  throw or return; do-something; } might require more memory than logically the equivalent {if (condition) throw/return; else do-something; }, since the memory might be allocated at the beginning of the block and not after skipping if statement. throw is just an example - memory might be allocated even if we never reach the constructor. Is this true? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @RazielMagius Yes, that's true. The entire stack frame is allocated at once, including the space for variables that might not be needed within the actually executed code path. Nevertheless, this is a non-issue: It would only be relevant if the allocation of the entire stack frame actually causes the stack to overflow (either an out-of-memory, or out-of-address-space condition). In all other cases, the stack pointer is decremented by some amount, some memory is used successfully, and the stack pointer is re-incremented. It does not matter how large that in/decrement offset is.

Comment: Btw: Huge objects (beyond a few kilobytes) should never be allocated on the stack anyways.

Answer (score 2):

The C++ standard has the following to say about it in *[basic.stc]* :

> 2 Static, thread, and automatic storage durations are associated with objects introduced by declarations (6.1) and implicitly created by the implementation (6.6.7).

This *6.6.7* reference refers to *[class.temporary]*, which is about temporaries. Temporaries aren't quite the same concept, but that section has this to say :

> 2 The materialization of a temporary object is generally delayed as long as possible in order to avoid creating unnecessary temporary objects.

I haven't found anything else that would address your question, so the standard appears to give the implementation some leeway as to when storage is allocated for the object.

Note this does not apply to when the object is initialized - that happens when the declaration statement is executed, as per *[stmt.dcl]* :

> 2 Variables with automatic storage duration (6.6.5.3) are initialized each time their *declaration-statement* is executed. Variables with automatic storage duration declared in the block are destroyed on exit from the block (8.6).

The [cppreference link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) you mentioned likely discusses a typical implementation, where objects with automatic storage duration are allocated on the stack. In such implementations, it makes sense to allocate storage at the start of an enclosing block (it's just a simple (in/de)crement of the stack pointer after all, and grouping them is beneficial).

If you want to avoid allocating storage for a huge object when not needed, restructuring the code is an option. On some implementations, introducing an additional block scope will achieve that :

```
{
    if(somecondition1) throw something;
    {
        MyHugeObject o{};
        /// do something
    }
}
```

On other implementations, other approaches might be needed. @DanielLangr's comment below indicates implementations where the allocation happens at the start of the enclosing function, rather than at the start of the block.

Comment: I am not sure if adding a block scope changes anything with common implementations. For instance, both GCC and Clang allocate memory for the block-scope object at the beginning of the function (by lowering `rsp`): [live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/oPMVKS).

Comment: @DanielLangr : fair remark - I didn't intend that to be a solution that will absolutely work (the standard doesn't guarantee it, so an implementation is free to do what it wants), but rather as one that *might* work. I'll clarify that.

Answer (score 2):

The moment at which the memory is reclaimed from the *system* is implementation dependant. The only thing that is mandated by the standard is the moment when the constructor is called and when the object can safely be used.

Common implementations use a stack for automatic storage duration objects, and most of the time *allocate* a whole frame at the beginning of a bloc and pop it at the end of the bloc. Even if stack operations are fast, it is simpler to limit their number, and the simpler is the more robust.

But anyway, even using a stack for automatic storage duration is not mandated by the standard, not speaking of the moment when frames are *allocated on* and *popped from* that stack.